# WSO2 API Manager - Restricting edit privilege on publisher site?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Currently, anyone who has creator role, can edit api published by someone else. Is there a way to restrict who can edit the api?

I guess, I could use multi-tenancy, but that may not work if they belong to the same departmnent.

Answer (score 1):

Nope currently there is no such a way. Permissions are bonded with the role; not with users of wso2 API manger. Therefore, most possible solution will the multi tenancy.

Comment: The problem is - I can create apis using different roles, where each role was created using "creator" privileges and still they can all edit each other's apis. Is this how it was intended or is it a bug?

Comment: This is how it is intended, say an API creator leaves an organisation then there is no way of managing the existing API. Hence it is possible for anyone with a creator role to edit API's. But the catch is not everyone can publish. So a person can edit any API he wants, but only a publisher can publish the API.